# bijectivity of operator imply the bijectivity of his composants

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a not-bounded operator in a Hilbert space $H$
and let $T_{\lambda}=Id+(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda}-1)(I-\lambda_0A)^{-1}$ 
such that $\lambda \leq \lambda_0$ then

\begin{align}
 T_{\lambda} &= (Id-\lambda_0A)(Id-\lambda_0A)^{-1}+(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda}-1)(Id-\lambda_0A)^{-1}  \\
        &= \{(Id-\lambda_0A)+(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda}-Id)\}(Id-\lambda_0A)^{-1} \\
  &= (-\lambda_0A+\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda})(Id-\lambda_0A)^{-1}\\
  &=  \frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda}(Id-\lambda A)(Id-\lambda_0A)^{-1} 
\end{align}

Can we conclud that $T_{\lambda}$ is bejective if and only if $(Id-\lambda A)$ is bijective ?

Can we considere the following example as a contre example 
$f;g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow  \mathbb{N}   $ such that

$
f(k)= \left\{
\begin{align}
\frac{k}{2} \quad     if  \quad  k  \quad even\\ 
\frac{k+1}{2} \quad if \quad k \quad odd 
\end{align}
\right.$

and  $g(k)=2k$
no one of them is bijective but $f \circ g (k)=k $ which is bijective !

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you are assuming that $Id-\lambda_0 A$ is bijective then the equivalence holds.

Comment: No, I am not, but I am trying to get it from the bijectivity of $(Id-\lambda A)$ when  $\lambda \leq \lambda_0$